# Adding response headers and/or custom message properties to isolated azure function response

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a function signature similar to the one below, and I'm looking to include HTTP response headers. However, I'm uncertain about its feasibility since the output involves another custom type being placed onto a different topic, rather than being HTTP-based. If adding HTTP response headers is not possible in this context, what would be the approach to include message properties along with the message body (MyResult)?

```
[Function(FunctionName)]
[ServiceBusOutput(OutputTopicName, Connection = "TriggerConnectionString")]
public async Task<MyResult?> RunAsync(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("%TriggerSource%", TriggerSubscriptionName, Connection = 
"TriggerConnectionString")]
    MyEvent? myEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   
}
```

I'm expecting/hoping for something like:

```
 public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
 {
     var messageProperties = context.GetMessageProperties();
     messageProperties.Add("new property, "value");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Followed [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for Azure Service Bus output bindings for Azure Functions

- The Sample could below send the messages to the Azure service bus Queue.

```cs
    var logger = context.GetLogger<ServiceBusOutputFunction>();

    try
    {
        // Send a new message to the output queue
        var outputMessage = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello, Azure Service Bus! This is an output message.");

        // Add custom properties to the message
        outputMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("CustomProperty1", "Value1");
        outputMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add("CustomProperty2", 42);

      
        await SendOutputMessage(outputMessage,context);

        return "Message processed successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the message.");
        throw;
    }
}

private static async Task SendOutputMessage(ServiceBusMessage message, FunctionContext context)
{
    var logger = context.GetLogger<ServiceBusOutputFunction>();

    string connectionString = " ServicebusConnectionString ";
    string outputQueueName = "ServiceBusQueueName"; // Replace with your output queue name

    // Create a Service Bus sender for the output queue
    await using (ServiceBusSender sender = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString).CreateSender(outputQueueName))
    {
        // Send the message to the output queue
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);

        logger.LogInformation($"Message sent to {outputQueueName}.");
    }
}
```

Output :
[image]